# wcf call completed event is not fired in correct order

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, silverlight

In my Silverlight application, I put the WCF call in my ViewModel class.

```
DateTime CurrentDateTime;
internal void GetDateTime()
{
    var client = new WcfClient();
    client.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted += GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
    client.GetCurrentDateTimeAsync();
}

private void GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted(object sender, GetCurrentDateTimeCompletedEventArgs args)
{
     try
     {
          CurrentDateTime = args.Result;
     }
```

Then in my code behind code some.xaml.cs file. I have a checkbox clicked event.

```
    private void CheckBox_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msgBoxControl = new MessageBoxControl();
                msgBoxControl.Closed -= MessageBoxYesNo_Closed;
                msgBoxControl.Closed += MessageBoxYesNo_Closed;
```

Inside the method `MessageBoxYesNo_Closed`, I call the method in the ViewModel class.

```
private void MessageBoxYesNo_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.ViewModel.GetDateTime();
        curDateTime = this.ViewModel.CurrentDateTime;
```

My question is that sometimes the line `curDateTime = this.ViewModel.CurrentDateTime;` is executed before wcf call completed method, so I can't get the right value.

I guess that it may be there are two threads, one is in UI, the other one is in service call? Please don't use async/await as I have to use Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Comment: The problem here (i suspect) is that the `GetCurrentDateTimeAsync` method is Asynchronous, which means that in your `MessageBoxYesNo_Closed` handler the `GetDateTime` method will return before it is completed. I have no experience with silverlight but I would suggest looking into using async/await if it is supported.

Comment: Indeed, you run asynchronous call to get time and then immediately ask the value from the control. But asynchronous request can be finished later. So, you can request data synchronously **GetCurrentDateTime** and then set the value into ViewModel, but it can freeze your UI thread if request takes too much time. Or use async/await to set *curDateTime* when asynchronous request is completed. But then it can be confusing for the user if he wants to see the time right after dialog is closed. Or you can use some wait indicator...

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010. So async/await is not supported.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is free :). Otherwise you will need to modify your code to not access `CurrentDateTime` until  the completed event has fired.

Comment: @Phaeze, I have to use VS 2010 and no choice. Not sure how to modify the code so I posted the question.

Comment: Why down vote it? Please give me a reason so I can learn something next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the solution, just add a while loop:

```
            this.ViewModel.GetDateTime();

            while (true)
            {
                this.ViewModel.CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                if (this.ViewModel.CurrentDateTime != DateTime.MinValue)
                    break;
            }
            curDateTime = this.ViewModel.CurrentDateTime;
```